# Intel DPDK compile

Tags: linux-kernel, dpdk

I have installed kernel-devel.
I got this. there are no questions like this on Internet.

```
[root @ fedora dpdk-1.6.0r1] # make
== Build scripts
== Build scripts / testhost
== Build lib
== Build lib / librte_eal
== Build lib / librte_eal / common
== Build lib / librte_eal / linuxapp
== Build lib / librte_eal / linuxapp / igb_uio
CC [M] / home/wangs/dpdk-1.6.0r1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.o
/ home/wangs/dpdk-1.6.0r1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.c: In function 'local_pci_num_vf' in :
/ home/wangs/dpdk-1.6.0r1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.c: 108: error : 'struct pci_dev' has no member named 'sriov' members
......
make [8]: *** [/ home/wangs/dpdk-1.6.0r1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.o] Error 1
make [7]: *** [_module_/home/wangs/dpdk-1.6.0r1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio] Error 2
make [6]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make [5]: *** [igb_uio.ko] Error 2
make [4]: ​​*** [igb_uio] Error 2
make [3]: *** [linuxapp] Error 2
make [2]: *** [librte_eal] Error 2
make [1]: *** [lib] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

what should I do?

Comment: what distro and kernel version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel headers installed in your system might be older. You might have installed kernel-devel, but your kernel might be an older version. Check for the minimum linux kernel requirements.